# CMD: powercfg -setacvalueindex with GUIDs does not work

Tags: cmd, powercfg

If I try to run this in CMD:

```
powercfg –setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEODIM 0
```

then nothing happens.
If I try this:

```
powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_VIDEO VIDEOIDLE 300
```

then it works?

What am I doing wrong?
I can change those setting manually in Windows, so it should work automatically as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

found it, needs
    /setacvalueindex
a slash, no joke :)